# Rails RABL respond_with error template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabl

Using RABL in Rails 3.2.x, given the following controller action:

```
respond_to :html, :json

def create
  @foo = Foo.create(params[:foo])
  respond_with @foo
end
```

Assuming the validation fails, how do you get respond_with to use a RABL template instead of the standard JSON hash of errors -- IE. I would like other model attributes besides the validation error message sent back along with the request.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this one out the hard way. You should create a custom responder for your application controller, or at least your individual response. See [Three reasons to love ActionController::Responder](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2009/8/31/three-reasons-love-responder/) for more details.

My solution:

```
# app/responders/api_responder.rb
class ApiResponder < ActionController::Responder
  def to_format
    case
    when has_errors?
      controller.response.status = :unprocessable_entity
    when post?
      controller.response.status = :created
    end

    default_render
  rescue ActionView::MissingTemplate => e
    api_behavior(e)
  end
end

# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  #...
  self.responder = ApiResponder
  #...
end
```

You could also use `respond_with @foo, responder: ApiResponder` instead.

Thanks to [haxney](https://github.com/haxney) for sending me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you need to remove the respond_to call at the top of the controller and remove the respond_with call within the action to get rabl render your rabl template.

Just add a respond_to block at the end of each action where you don't need RABL.